# Authenticating an MVC application with tokens WebAPI

Tags: model-view-controller, jwt, webapi

I have written a basic WebAPI that authenticates using Jwt Tokens. When I make a test API call using Postman I get a token issued successfully. I am however stuck in getting my MVC application to authenticate using the tokens.

Here is the controller for the API -

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("login")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] LoginModel model)
    {
        var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Username);
        if (user != null && await userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, model.Password))
        {

            var authClaims = new[]
            {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.UserName),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
            };

            var authSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("YVBy0OLlMQG6VVVp1OH7Xzyr7gHuw1qvUC5dcGt3SBM="));

            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer: "https://localhost:44350",
                audience: "https://localhost:44350",
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddHours(3),
                claims: authClaims,
                signingCredentials: new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SigningCredentials(authSigningKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
                );

            return Ok(new
            {
                token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token),
                expiration = token.ValidTo
            });
        }
        return Unauthorized();
    }
```

Here is the Startup.cs for the WebAPI -

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.SaveToken = true;
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidAudience = "https://localhost:44350/",
                ValidIssuer = "https://localhost:44350/",
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("AA873344gshtrhjLJKJSLKF8u4o8grwieot4KJHFs9847GGSD"))
            };
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });

        SeedDB.Initialize(app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope().ServiceProvider);
    }
}
```

My code for the MVC applicaiton controller is below. It generates a token successfully, but I cant work out how to populate HttpContext.User.Identity?

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index(LoginModel login)
    {
        string url = BaseUrl + "api/authenticate/login";

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);

            var postTask = client.PostAsJsonAsync<LoginModel>("login", login);
            postTask.Wait();

            var result = postTask.Result;
            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var user = HttpContext.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;

                var tokenDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);

                var claims = new Claim[]
                {
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, login.Username, "string"),
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.Integer64)
                };

                user.AddClaims(claims);

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", null);
            }
        }

        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Server error");

        return View(login);
    }
```

Here is the Startup.cs for the MVC application

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();



        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add authentication service and use authentication middleware in the `startup.cs`:

```
services.AddAuthentication(option =>
{
    option.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    option.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(option =>
    {
        option.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        option.SaveToken = true;
        option.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            RequireExpirationTime = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidIssuer = "Some Issuer",
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudience = "Some Audience",
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Security Key")),
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        };
});
```

Also add `app.UseAuthentication();` to the `Configure` method in `startup.cs`.

Comment: is this in the WebAPI project or the MVC project? Its already in the WebAPI and I have added the above to the MVC (changed the issuer, audience and security key to match WebAPI one). Still HttpContext.User.Identity is null. I feel the error is in the MVC Login controller its not setting the HttpContext.User.Identity...

Comment: @dynmatt It is a WebAPI2 project but generally there is no difference. Please provide more details about sending jwt token, `startup.cs` and the place you are checking token validation.

Comment: I have added the Startup.cs for both WebAPI and MVC application to the original post. This is all the code I have really, the login API generates the token and the MVC Actionresult calls the API and gets a token successfully. Its just the MVC app doesnt seem to actually log in to the Identity?